# Using ZoneMinder Installation

Tags: 20.04, zoneminder

Ubuntu 20.04

ZoneMinder does not appear as an installable application so I used `apt-get` which worked without errors.

The package seems properly installed but does not appear in my **Applications** folder and will not run from the command line.

Is this application usable under Ubuntu?
If so, please advise how to run it and make it appear with my other applications.

Answer (score 1):

This application is web-based, not GUI - therefore it [does not have](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/zoneminder/filelist) any **.desktop*  file, so it is absolutely expected that its icon is not presented in menu.

You have to check its Apache configuration and use web-browser to get access to it.
Other good place to find help is [official documentation](https://zoneminder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installationguide/ubuntu.html) (with assumption that you use ZoneMinder from official Ubuntu repositories).

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what that means really but I will see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

ZoneMinder is actually a server. It's not a desktop application. However, it has a web-based interface that you can use.

#### Start the server:

You can start your ZoneMinder with:

```
sudo service zoneminder start
```

#### Access the web application:

You can access your ZoneMinder installation from your browser: `http://localhost/zm/`

#### Troubleshooting:

- If you get `ERROR 404` you may need to enable it by doing this:

  ```
  sudo a2enconf zoneminder
  sudo service apache2 restart
  ```
- If you get `ERROR 500`, there is something wrong with your installation and better read the official [Ubuntu Server or Desktop Zoneminder Installation Manual](https://wiki.zoneminder.com/Ubuntu_Server_or_Desktop_Zoneminder_1.36.x).